# WDS slow install using private Subnet

Tags: windows, networking, wds

I've have an Microsoft WDS server with 2 network interfaces.
Primary Network interface to be used by management, it's the main one with an standard configuration (routing,dns and connected to Active Directory)

The second Network interface is connected to a different/private subnet that is dedicated to perform image deployments.
This second network interface is not routed.

With this setup I was able to perform the pxe boot and I'm also able to start WDS windows setup.
The problem is during the Image installation deployment, that its very, very, very slow.

For the test I've did I've determined that is a network problem, but I don't know how can I solve it.

Any idea how to configure the network setting interfaces for this server to improve WDS deployments?

Best Regads

Answer (score 0):

I've improved the network connection excluding my primary Interface from WDS

wdsutil /set-server /bindpolicy /policy:exclude /add /address:x.x.x.x /AddressType:IP

Now althought it is not a rocket speed, at least is reasonable.

Any other suggestions would  be welcomed